# "Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" - depending on the size of the For Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am making script for companyOfficers of S&P 500 with data from Yahoo Finace. My script is working when For Loop is covering approximately 60 companies. if I make script to cover from 0 to 70 receive error "Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". I now that issue is coming from .iloc[0] but do not know how to fix it and why for smaller For Cycle there is not issue. Could you please support me to fix the issue, I want to run script for all S&P 500 companies.

That script is working normal

```
#Extracting actual companies in S&P 500 Index
table=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
sp500 = table[0]
sp500 = sp500["Symbol"].tolist()
sp500_len = len(sp500)

l = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(0,60):
    stock = yf.Ticker(sp500[x])
    df0=stock.info
    df0=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df0.items())
    df0.columns =['Name', 'Value'] 
    df0=df0.loc[df0['Name'] == 'companyOfficers']
    df0.drop(columns=['Name'])
    df0=df0['Value'].iloc[0]
    df0=pd.DataFrame(df0)
    df0['Stock'] = sp500[x]
    df0=df0.head(1)
    l = pd.concat([l, df0], axis=0)
```

For that script receive $Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds$

```
#Extracting actual companies in S&P 500 Index
table=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
sp500 = table[0]
sp500 = sp500["Symbol"].tolist()
sp500_len = len(sp500)

l = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(0,70):
    stock = yf.Ticker(sp500[x])
    df0=stock.info
    df0=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df0.items())
    df0.columns =['Name', 'Value'] 
    df0=df0.loc[df0['Name'] == 'companyOfficers']
    df0.drop(columns=['Name'])
    df0=df0['Value'].iloc[0]
    df0=pd.DataFrame(df0)
    df0['Stock'] = sp500[x]
    df0=df0.head(1)
    l = pd.concat([l, df0], axis=0)
```

Research about .iloc[0] but could not find how to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

What you see is that some tickers doesn't return `companyOfficers` form `yfinance` (e.g. as for ticker `BRK.B`). You can check for that condition:

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

sp500=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]

comp_officers = []
for x in sp500["Symbol"][60:70]:  # <-- adjust here the wanted range
    stock = yf.Ticker(x)
    i = stock.info.get('companyOfficers', [{}])[0]
    comp_officers.append({**i, 'stock': x})

df = pd.DataFrame(comp_officers)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   maxAge                           name   age                 title  yearBorn  fiscalYear    totalPay  exercisedValue  unexercisedValue  stock
0     1.0      Mr. Brian Thomas Moynihan  63.0  Chairman, CEO & Pres    1959.0      2022.0   1975176.0             0.0               0.0    BAC
1     1.0            Ms. Gina R. Boswell  59.0        CEO & Director    1963.0      2022.0   3055967.0             0.0               0.0   BBWI
2     1.0            Mr. Jose E. Almeida  60.0  Chairman, Pres & CEO    1962.0      2022.0   2097448.0             0.0         9985352.0    BAX
3     1.0        Mr. Thomas E. Polen Jr.  49.0  Pres, CEO & Chairman    1973.0      2022.0   3929182.0       1887735.0          841384.0    BDX
4     1.0     Mr. William Robert Berkley  77.0        Exec. Chairman    1945.0      2022.0  12859029.0             0.0               0.0    WRB
5     NaN                            NaN   NaN                   NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN             NaN               NaN  BRK.B
6     1.0            Ms. Corie Sue Barry  47.0        CEO & Director    1975.0      2023.0   1838257.0             0.0         7036977.0    BBY
7     1.0         Mr. Norman D. Schwartz  72.0  Chairman, CEO & Pres    1950.0      2022.0   2129637.0      15227430.0        34999260.0    BIO
8     1.0         Mr. Charles R. Kummeth  62.0  CEO, Pres & Director    1960.0      2022.0   5071187.0      31638464.0       155919776.0   TECH
9     1.0  Mr. Christopher A. Viehbacher  61.0  Pres, CEO & Director    1961.0      2022.0    487938.0             0.0               0.0   BIIB
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it is really works, I did not image that issue could came from missing values